# How to deploy Flask app as a windows service over HTTPS?

Tags: python, flask, windows-services, wsgiserver

Using Flask API and WSGIServer, I'm able to launch it over HTTPS. But, I want our API as a windows service. So, when I run windows service and hit "https://127.0.0.1:88", I'm getting "Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established". Any advice on how to fix or debug.

See code snippets below.

```
import sys
import servicemanager
import win32serviceutil
from gevent import pywsgi

#Flask App
from myapp import app


class Service(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "MyService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "MyServer"
    _svc_description_ = "MyAPI"

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

        self.http_server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 88), app, keyfile='privateKey.key', certfile='certificate.crt')

        self.SvcStop = self.http_server.stop
        self.SvcDoRun = self.http_server.serve_forever

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(Service)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(Service)
```